# Can you automatically load user information in kivy

Tags: python, save, load, kivy, textinput

I am making an app where there is a profile screen in which you can enter generic profile information (name, height, weight, ect..) using textinput boxes.  I know there is a way to put a button next to each textinput box to save the information and another button to load the information.  I am wondering if there is a way to automatically load this information when the user opens the app rather than manually loading the information by hitting a button.

```
<Phone>:
result: _result
h: _h
w: _w


AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'

    ScreenManager:
        size_hint: 1, .9
        id: _screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'home'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    source: "/home/aaron/Desktop/main.png"
            Label:
                markup: True
                text: '[size=100][color=ff3333]Welcome to [color=ff3333]Diabetes Manager[/color][/size]'
        Screen:
            name: 'menu'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 2
                padding: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "/home/aaron/Desktop/main.png"

                Button:
                    text: 'My Profile'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'profile' 
                Button:
                    text: 'History'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'history'     

                Button:
                    text: 'New Entry'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'new_entry' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Graph'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'graph' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Diet'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'diet' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'settings' 

        Screen:
            name: 'profile'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 1
                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Name[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _name
                        hint_text: 'Name'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:  
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Gender[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _gender1
                        hint_text: 'Gender'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=34][color=0000ff]Type of Diabetes[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _type
                        hint_text: 'Type of Diabetes'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Height (in)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _h
                        hint_text: 'Height in inches'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Weight (lb)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _w
                        hint_text: 'Weight in pounds'

                BoxLayout:
                    Button:
                        text: 'Calculate BMI'
                        on_press: root.product(*args)

                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 4.5
                        id:_result
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]BMI[/color][/size]'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=30][color=0000ff]List of Medications[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _meds
                        hint_text: 'List of Medications'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=38][color=0000ff]Insulin Times[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _times
                        hint_text: 'Please Enter Times to Take Insulin'


        Screen:
            name: 'history'
            GridLayout: 
                cols:1

        Screen:
            name: 'new_entry'
            GridLayout:
                cols:1

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Time[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _time
                        hint_text: 'Current Time'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=28][color=0000ff]Blood Sugar (mg/dL)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _glucose_reading
                        hint_text: 'Current Blood Sugar'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Carbs[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _food
                        hint_text: 'Total Carbs for meal'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=30][color=0000ff]Medications Taken[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _meds_taken
                        hint_text: 'Please Enter Any Medications Taken'


        Screen:
            name: 'graph'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Your Graph[/color][/size]'

        Screen:
            name: 'diet'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Reccomended Diet[/color][/size]'


        Screen:
            name: 'settings'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Settings[/color][/size]'


AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'bottom'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            id: btnExit
            text: 'Exit'
            on_press: app.stop() 
        Button:
            text: 'Menu'
            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'menu'
```

Answer (score 3):

Kivy uses a [subclass of `ConfigParser`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html#kivy.config.ConfigParser) to parse standard `ini` files. Documentation on how to use this to load [app-specific settings](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#application-configuration) is on the kivy.app doc page.

From the docs:

```
class TestApp(App):
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('section1', {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': '42'
        })

    def build(self):
        config = self.config
        return Label(text='key1 is %s and key2 is %d' % (
            config.get('section1', 'key1'),
            config.getint('section1', 'key2')))
```

Comment: I've totally forgotten about this option! O_o

Comment: How would you go about doing this? I've entered my kivy file

Answer (score 2):

You can save the info in a json (import `json`) file, and load it using [on_start](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#profiling-with-on-start-and-on-stop) event method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, each `App` starts with `build()` function expecting a root widget to be returned, so either you can make a simple file loading with a function inside your `App` class and push values to each widget through `ids` or through root's widget `children`

or do the same loading function inside `__init__()` of your class where the widget values you want to update are.

For example `class MyBox(BoxLayout)` is a class with children which values you want to update. Then you call your loading function inside `MyBox.__init__()`. You can simplify it even more: use the loading function inside `__init__()` and create a list/dictionary/variables where you'll pass the values. Inside `kv` file you'll just access the variables through for example `root.<variable>`.