# How to automatically save and load user input kivy

Tags: android, python, save, load, kivy

I am making an app where there is a profile screen in which you can enter generic profile information (name, height, weight, ect..) using textinput boxes. I know there is a way to put a button next to each textinput box to save the information and another button to load the information. I am wondering if there is a way to automatically load this information when the user opens the app rather than manually loading the information by hitting a button.  Some have suggested ussing a subclass of ConfigParser to parse standard ini files and use this to load app-specific settings, but I have no idea how to do this.

Kivy File:

```
<Phone>:
result: _result
h: _h
w: _w


AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'

    ScreenManager:
        size_hint: 1, .9
        id: _screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'home'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    source: "/home/aaron/Desktop/main.png"
            Label:
                markup: True
                text: '[size=100][color=ff3333]Welcome to [color=ff3333]Diabetes Manager[/color][/size]'
        Screen:
            name: 'menu'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 2
                padding: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "/home/aaron/Desktop/main.png"

                Button:
                    text: 'My Profile'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'profile' 
                Button:
                    text: 'History'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'history'     

                Button:
                    text: 'New Entry'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'new_entry' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Graph'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'graph' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Diet'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'diet' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'settings' 

        Screen:
            name: 'profile'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 1
                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Name[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _name
                        hint_text: 'Name'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:  
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Gender[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _gender1
                        hint_text: 'Gender'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=34][color=0000ff]Type of Diabetes[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _type
                        hint_text: 'Type of Diabetes'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Height (in)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _h
                        hint_text: 'Height in inches'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Weight (lb)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _w
                        hint_text: 'Weight in pounds'

                BoxLayout:
                    Button:
                        text: 'Calculate BMI'
                        on_press: root.product(*args)

                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 4.5
                        id:_result
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]BMI[/color][/size]'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=30][color=0000ff]List of Medications[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _meds
                        hint_text: 'List of Medications'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=38][color=0000ff]Insulin Times[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _times
                        hint_text: 'Please Enter Times to Take Insulin'


        Screen:
            name: 'history'
            GridLayout: 
                cols:1

        Screen:
            name: 'new_entry'
            GridLayout:
                cols:1

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Time[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _time
                        hint_text: 'Current Time'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=28][color=0000ff]Blood Sugar (mg/dL)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _glucose_reading
                        hint_text: 'Current Blood Sugar'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Carbs[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _food
                        hint_text: 'Total Carbs for meal'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=30][color=0000ff]Medications Taken[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _meds_taken
                        hint_text: 'Please Enter Any Medications Taken'


        Screen:
            name: 'graph'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Your Graph[/color][/size]'

        Screen:
            name: 'diet'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Reccomended Diet[/color][/size]'


        Screen:
            name: 'settings'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Settings[/color][/size]'


AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'bottom'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            id: btnExit
            text: 'Exit'
            on_press: app.stop() 
        Button:
            text: 'Menu'
            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'menu'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you automatically load user information in kivy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269812/can-you-automatically-load-user-information-in-kivy)

Comment: couldn’t delete my last question and wanted to add my code before people started answering

Comment: Just a general comment: it is usually better to understand a new concept with some toy examples rather than a full application. Cf [ask] and [mcve]. More specific: The documentation I linked to in my answer to your earlier question shows exactly how to init config and how to read config values to populate a `Label`. I suggest you play with that example, figure out how to apply it. Then, if things are still unclear, ask a specific question, with a small example.

Comment: I am confused as to how I would be able to save the textinput information.  I have an ID for each textinput but how would I recall the input afterwards?

Comment: Probably, you'd want to save this when you leave the `Screen` containing the `TextInput`s. So the method that runs when you leave the `profile` screen should access each `TextInput` by `id`, retrieve its `text` and save it to some config item.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy has storage functionality inbuilt. By using the inbuilt methods it will store the file in the correct place for Android or iOS without you having to worry about the correct location. Here's their docs:
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html#module-kivy.storage

And a short example to show how to put, retrieve and delete values:

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore('baz.json')
store.put('foo', 'bar')

if store.exists('foo'):
    print('foo is:', store.get('foo'))
    store.delete('foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that jsonstore is too limited you cant add more info using one textinput meaning whenever you want to save new info it will delete the old one. so JsonStore its for registering new user(Loging and sign up) or something you wont or will change and put new info

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34390584)